# What target is build when I just Build my Xcode project

Tags: xcode, xcode4

If I just build my Xcode 4 project (using the cmd-B) command, which target is built?

I'm having trouble understanding the new scheme setup. When I look at the currently selected scheme, under the "Build" tab, all my different build types are checked (ie: Analyze, Test, Run, Profile, Archive). However, when I build, it seems like only "Run" is built. And for the *.app file that is produced, is this built using the "Build Configuration" set under the "Run" tab?

Thanks!

Sunny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever target that is in selection next to your Run, Stop button in your Xcode.